# How to debug Android and/or iOS apps on a Windows Desktop Environment

Tags: ios, debugging, analytics, android

I work with web analytics and have somewhat of a web developer background, BUT I am not a programmer.  I need a way to debug the tracking code I request our mobile app team to implement.  They are also not Web Analysts so they struggle to be able to verify if it works too.

I need a way to take one of their builds, run it on a desktop environment, and monitor it with a network monitoring tool like Charles Proxy or the network monitoring tools in the developer tools of most browsers.

I want to at least be able to see the information being passed back to our analytics tracking tool via the network connection.  That will tell me if what I requested works or not.  If there are other tools that a non-programmer can use to achieve this and more I would be grateful to hear about them.  The few tools I have seen seem to be more about testing web pages via a mobile device.  I need to test apps that you will eventually download from the an app store.

Thanks!

Comment: I dont't really understand what you are looking for. Charles Proxy should catch all the requests (If you have all the certificates in place). Analytics from the web should look very similar to what you would see in an iOS or Android app

Comment: Thanks for the response, SinzianaG! I am having difficulty understanding how to use Charles Proxy for a mobile device.  How do you get traffic from the device to route through my desktop (which is where Charles Proxy is installed) so I can monitor it?  That is the piece I am not understanding. Last time I checked, Charles Proxy doesn't have a mobile app version of their tool.

Comment: The easiest way to do that is to share your internet connection from your laptop over wifi, connect your tablet to the computer and when you connect it add the computer's IP address and port 8888 as a proxy for that connection. If everything is fine you should be able to catch even the requests made from the tablet browser. Once that's done you should see the analytics events also.

Answer (score 0):

In our company, we found that Charles is perfect for testing all that concerns tracking.

Charles will record all your requests and responses from your computer, SSL traffic included.

(You can also let physical Android/iOS devices use your desktop as a proxy to catch all traffic there, which is even more impressive and useful, but I understand that this is not what you want.)

You can even do fancy stuff like throttling your connection and adding breakpoints, to see what would happen in "real" situations with bad connection...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you associated with Charles Proxy in any way?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I use Charles Proxy a lot for desktop website testing.  How do you use it for mobile apps? Last I checked they didn't have an app for mobile devices.

Comment: @user3842539 Like he said; set the PC/Mac as the proxy for the mobile device.

Comment: Thanks guys!  I found some info on the Charles Proxy site on how to do this. http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/.  I've never done this before but should be able to figure it out with this tutorial.  Thanks again!

Comment: @trojanfoe: No, I'm not associated with Charles Proxy. I work as a PM in mobile app development in Germany; we use Charles for debugging and testing.

I am however quite enthusiastic about Charles, because it gave me so much control over my otherwise mysterious handset.